# Frequency response measurement problem with mobile phone: same (wrong?) readings for different speakers

Tags: speakers, sound, frequency-measurement, frequency-response

I have built some bespoke speakers and tried to measure their frequency response.

My rig is:

**Source:**
Android phone Samsung A3 as a source, playing frequency sweep using Android's Frequency Generator App 20Hz-20KHZ.

Amp: NAD 3020,

Speakers: bespoke transmission line with driver's Fs =84Hz, tuned at 60Hz. My calculations show that's where the bass roll-off should start.

**Measurement:**
Samsung A3 with DaytonAudio IMM-6 measurement microphone (Working range 20Hz-20KHz +-1dB).
I carry out measurement in an ordinary room, without much draping, at about 30 cm away from the driver, so I do not expect to see any nice smooth distribution.

What I see is shown in the image below. Which I believe is wrong, since the roll-off should be at about 60Hz. I've measured the other speakers I own and I can see very similar frequency response, although their woofer driver has Fs = 60 Hz and should play much deeper than the first speakers I measure. The result below is captured with the Spectroid App, but I tried a few other with the same effect.

On the picture, my reading is red (max hold in Specroid), yellow is the current sweep.

Could anyone shed the light as to what I'm doing wrong:

1. Is it possible that the mobile phone only produces useful bass from 100Hz Or the amp is wonky? That sounds hardly plausible as the music plays rather nicely, with full-bodied punchy bass.
2. Is it microphone's fault? I also tried to plug the microphone to a tablet and the laptop and use devices' own microphone - with very similar result.
3. Is it the software fault?
4. Is it the room or my method that is to blame?

And finally, has anyone successfully measured their speakers's frequency response in a similar ad-hoc set up and how did you go about it?

PS: Sadly all the equipment I have at my disposal is what I listed above, plus the multimeter and the solder. I'm a proper noob when it comes to electrical engineering and signal measurements - the simper suggestions are the better!

[image]

Comment: Measure what comes out of the amplifier to have a decent comparison. There are two spectra in the picture, which one is which?

Comment: how do I do that? Do I need an osicilloscope or something? I don't have that...The red spectrum is my reading, yellow is a current sweep

Comment: Bypass the microphone and use an attenuator to feed the A3. In other words get the spectrum of what feeds the speaker but, USE AN ATTENUATOR to avoid damaging the A3.

Comment: Sadly all the equipment I have at my dsposal is what I listed above, plus the multimeter. I'm a proper noob when it comes to electrical engineering and signal measurements

Comment: Try a much larger room or even outdoors on a very still day. (Or a smaller room for a comparative result)

Comment: Have you seen how **professionals** do this kind of measurements? Common theme: **they use a dead room** to prevent the sound waves bouncing of walls etc. Escpecially at lower frequencies, **the room** can make or break the frequency response.

Comment: @NestorMilyaev You can make an attenuator with just a few resistors. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuator_(electronics)

Comment: And can I then I connect it to a microphone input in the mobile  phone?

Comment: You have far too many unknowns here, eg in the phone output DSP software and hardware, the microphone input, you might even be hitting an AGC somewhere.